# insert data of the combobox to my student table

Tags: c#, postgresql, parsing, visual-c++, combobox

Hey i have a app to create students and add there classes and Faculty,
when i try to add the the student with his faculty i have a problem because i am choosing the classes and faculty from a combobox that from a table called classes that shows u what are the classes are  like this

```
        {
            conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
            conn.Open();
            sql = @"select * from  class";
            cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());


            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
               comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["nom_class"].ToString());


            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

that one show the classes for me in my app like this 
[image]

and now the for the problem is can't find a way to add the class when try to insert the student because the combobox shows me the table of the name of class and for the student i have a id_class that's a foreigner key for the real id_class in class but i in the combobox there is charecters and i can't add 
because the id_class is type of int and in the combobox can't change row into values like First row =1 and Second ROW = 2  i tryed to do it like this but it didn't work

```
    conn.Open();
                sql = "insert into etudiant  (Nom, prenom, sexe,classess) " +
                     "values(@Nom, @prenom,  @sexe,@classess)"/*+"class (nom_class)" + "values(@nom_class) "*/;
                    cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nom", bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prenom", bunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sexe", bunifuMaterialTextbox3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@classess",int.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()));
```

btw it works fine without the combobox 
any help would be nice

Answer (score 0):

If i get everything right:

```
int id = comboBox1.SelectedIndex +1;
```

The index is based with 0 so you have to add +1